# Convolution in frequency domain

Tags: laplace-transform

I have a time domain function$[f(t)=\cos(wt).e^{-t^{2}}]$

I want to find out the laplace transform of the above function.

The convolution property says that  a product in time domain can be obtained as a convolution in frequency domain.

So, I can obtain the laplace transform of $f(t)$ as $F(s)= \left[\frac{s}{s^{2} + w^{2}}\right] *\left[\frac{5.7s^{2} -18.2s + 92.416}{s^{5}+8.3s^{4}+33s^{3}+74.8s^{2}+94.5s + 52.3}\right]
$

where $\left[\frac{s}{s^{2} + w^{2}}\right]$ is the laplace transform of $\cos(wt)$ and $\left[\frac{5.7s^{2} -18.2s + 92.416}{s^{5}+8.3s^{4}+33s^{3}+74.8s^{2}+94.5s + 52.3}\right]$ is the laplace transform of $e^{-t^{2}}$ (which is obtained by rational approximation) and $*$ stands for convolution

How can the final expression for $F(s)$ be obtained?

Comment: Oh, I see! Sorry! :)

Comment: @gmakkena, do you know definition of [convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Definition) of two functions?

Comment: Yes Sir. So can I get the final expression by integrating both the expressions?

Comment: You just put these expressions into the integral and integrate, yes, this is by definition. BTW, your rational approximation looks quite off the result I got using `LaplaceTransform` Mathematica function: see [this image](http://i.imgur.com/fNTMlXz.png): here blue curve is closed form solution, and purple one is your approximation. Taking inverse transform suggests that you approximate $e^{-(t-2)^2}$ instead of $e^{-t^2}$.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply sir. According to my understanding Mathematica would use symbolic math to generate the solution and the plot would be close to ideal. Whereas I need a rational approximation so that I can get the practical implementation and would be having an error. Thanks for pointing this out, I shall increase the order of my rational approximation so that the error reduces. You are right sir it is  $e^−(t−2)^2$ i am approximating. Sorry for the typo

Comment: @Ruslan Can I use the Convolve symbol available in mathematica to obtain the same?

Comment: `Convolve` _function_ gives you the convolution indeed, see help.

Comment: @Ruslan Many thanks...i shall try convolve function and get back

Comment: @Ruslan I have used the Convolve function. This is the code below g[s] = s/(s^2 + 4)
h[s] = (5.7*s^2 - 18.2*s + 92.416)/(s^5 + 8.3*s^4 + 33*s^3 +
    74.8*s^2 + 94.5*s + 52.3)
Convolve[g[s], h[s], s, x]                                      Mathematica seems to run forever and is not able to give out a solution!

Comment: Not surprising, the integral doesn't seem trivial. It may even not be able to integrate this at all. You might have to use numerical ways of solving your problem.

Comment: @Ruslan Alas!...Back to square one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your definition of $f(t)$ only holds for $t>0$, and that $f(t)=0$ for $t<0$. In this case

$$f(t)=\cos(wt)e^{-t^2}u(t)$$

where $u(t)$ is the Heaviside step function. The function

$$g(t)=e^{-t^2}u(t)$$

has a [closed-form Laplace transform](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=laplace%20transform%20e%5E%28-t%5E2%29):

$$G(s)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}e^{s^2/4}\text{erfc}(s/2)$$

Note that $f(t)$ can be written as

$$f(t)=\cos(wt)g(t)=\frac12\left(e^{iwt}g(t)+e^{-iwt}g(t)\right)$$

Now you can use the shifting property of the Laplace transform to obtain

$$F(s)=\frac12\left(G(s-iw)+G(s+iw)\right)$$

Comment: many thanks for the answer. I was able to solve my problem and obtain a rational form for my final expression.